# What is the proper format for defining and printing string variables in C?

Tags: c, string, variables, printf

I'm an absolute beginner to C, I've had some experiences with other high level languages like Ruby and Python, but other than that I'm also a beginner to programming in general.  I've been trying to figure out how to define a string variable and print it using something like the "printf" function, but so far I've had no luck since my code just keeps spitting out error messages.

From what I understand, something like this should define a string variable and then print it to the console:

```
char string[3];
string = "hi";
printf ("%s", string);
```

But this doesn't work, so what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is completely useless as a problem description. Always include the errors you're getting (exactly as you see them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work because you cannot assign to arrays in C, except when initializing them.

So, you can do:

```
char string[3] = "hi";
```

which is better (safer) written as:

```
char string[] = "hi";
```

this lets the compiler worry about the character-count, and is generally preferable.

To change the array contents after initialization, you must use some function that can copy the characters, you cannot do this with a single assignment:

```
strcpy(string, "yo");
```

note that this is *dangerous* since `strcpy()` will not be aware of the array's limit of 3 characters.

Comment: Is there a safer function to use?  Or do you just need to be careful when redefining variables?

Comment: Worth mentioning also assigning the string literal to a pointer, I suspect that's what he meant

Comment: @nattinthehat There is a function called strncpy (notice the 'n') which accepts a third parameter 'N' and will copy 'up to N' characters

You would use it like this `strncpy(string, "yo", 3)`. Careful, though, about the string-terminating null-byte. strncpy will not check it for you.